# Google Calendar's API sample Project for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I have gone through the following links
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/detail?name=LatestLibrarySources.txt&can=2&q=
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

I have found the SDK for Google Calendar but is there any Valid Sample Project/POC using Google Calendar. The one i mentioned is not working and gives compile time errors.

Comment: Here is the link https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Calendar/Generated/GTLQueryCalendar.m#49 for the calendar API in objective-c

Comment: There is nothing like Sample project in it :) I have downloaded that code earlier.